# Sharepoint Designer workflow: prevent from executing if column input is empty

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, column

I've made a workflow that checks for a date-column and if the current date is bigger than the date-column it updates an item.

[image]

**The problem:** even if the date-column is empty it updates the item.

**Desired situation:** don't update the item if date-column is empty.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is structured, it will do that regardless of what the conditions are. You need to move the daarna Item and daarna Email actions up into the if block, immediately after the pause step. While a subtle change, the effects are what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Eric, mm I use the Loop as an kind of constant workflow. Recheck every x minutes. If I put it in the Loop the actions are executed regardless of the conditions that are met?

Comment: Oh, thats a loop? Why are you looping? Are you waiting for an action to occur? It seems more like you'd just want to do If column is greater than or equal to column, update and email as one step, which would still look similar to what I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a workflow variable of **boolean type** and set it's value to **No**.

   2. Use the action, **if any value equals value**
   3. In the first value,select your date column.
   4. Click on **equals** and change it to **is empty**
   5. In the if block, set the Boolean variable to **Yes**.
   6. Outside this if, create another **if any value equals value** action.
   7. In this action, check boolean variable to be **No**.
   8. In the if block write the code for your update.